# ArgumentNullException when DataBind() called on DropDownList

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, argumentnullexception

When I call `DataBind()` on a DropDownList in ASP.NET 4, it's throwing an ArgumentNullException:

> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name:
>   container  at System.Web.UI.DataBinder.GetPropertyValue(Object
>   container, String propName) at
>   System.Web.UI.DataBinder.GetPropertyValue(Object container, String
>   propName, String format)  at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable
>   dataSource)  at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e)  at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.PerformSelect()  at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() at
>   MyNamespace.MyClass.MyFunction()

Here is my code:

```
myDropdown.Items.Clear();
myDropdown.ClearSelection();
myDropdown.Items.Add(new ListItem("-Select-", "-1"));
myDropdown.DataSource = myDataSource; //List<T> of my business objects
myDropdown.DataBind();
```

I found [this forum post](http://forums.asp.net/p/1593029/4039721.aspx) that seems to suggest taking away the DataValueField and DataTextField settings on the dropdown, which I've set in markup.  When I do that and change the second-to-last line of my code to this so I still get meaningful text in the options:

```
myDropdown.DataSource = myDataSource.Select(elem => new ListItem(elem.Text, elem.Id));
```

...it still doesn't work.  It does work, though, when I take away the line that adds the "-Select-" option.  And it only breaks when there is no element selected before it's data bound.

What's going on?

Comment: What does `List<T>` holds? Check whether it's empty or not?

Comment: @Rahul - see my answer below.  I found what was causing the error.  The cause of the cause is a mystery for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Further Google searching found [this other post](http://geekswithblogs.net/samerpaul/archive/2009/08/16/ldquovalue-cannot-be-null.-parameter-name-containerrdquo.aspx) that suggests that null objects in the datasource can cause this problem.  I changed my DataSource line to this:

```
myDropdown.DataSource = myDataSource.Where(elem => elem != null);
```

And it worked.

I have yet to determine why/how I have null values in that list.  Hmm.